# dynamically change alternate row colors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5 tr, these are row alternate color.  Now how to change tr color dynamically when I delete some row.

Assume below is table tr and td

this is my row

```
tr class='odd'  
tr class='even'
tr class='odd'
tr class='even'
tr class='odd'
tr class='even'
tr class='odd'


tr class='odd'
tr class='even' if I delete this tr, than 
tr class='odd'
tr class='even'
tr class='odd'
tr class='even'
tr class='odd'


tr class='odd'
tr class='even'  class changed  odd to even
tr class='odd'   class changed  even to odd
tr class='even'  class changed  odd to even
tr class='odd'   class changed  even to odd
tr class='even'  
tr class='odd'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
$('table tr:even td').css("background-color":"");
$('table tr:odd td').css("background-color":"");
```

Comment: but we cant guess user which row going to del, so how to reassign tow color alternativly

Comment: just re-assign colors after delete

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Zebra striping in JQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aZebra_Striping_Made_Easy)